# Error while reading an XML and validating the schema with XMLReader in PHP

Tags: php, c, xml, xmlreader

I'm having the following PHP code block:

```
    if (file_exists($name)) {
    $reader = new XMLReader();
    $reader->open($name);
    $reader->setSchema('inc/schema.xsd');

    while($reader->read());
    $reader->close();
} else {
    die("you're having trouble with the files!");
}
```

For certain URLs I'm getting the following error:

> Warning: XMLReader::read(): Unimplemented block at
>   ..\xmlschemas.c:28351 in xml2csv.php on line
>   43
>
> Warning: XMLReader::read(): An Error Occurred while reading in
>   xml2csv.php on line 43
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Premature end of data in tag Products
>   line 1 in products.xml, line:
>   532571 in xml2csv.php on line 55

Mostly, the URLs that give me this problem are local URLs (when $name = "file.xml") or remote URLs (when $name = "http://www.domain.com/products.xml") are broken (returning 404, 500, etc.).

A simple Google search on the error brought me to this: https://github.com/Chronic-Dev/libxml2/blob/master/xmlschemas.c

At the line mentioned, 28351, it seems there's a text saying TODO. Because my C skills are very limited (as in close to nothing), I'd like to better understand the reasons of this error and how can I avoid bumping into it.

Comment: Have you found any solution? I need to validate quite large XML file with PHP and I really would like to use XMLReader for that. But I receive the same error "Warning: XMLReader::read(): Unimplemented block at ../../xmlschemas.c:28351 in /cloudware/application/modules/otms/models/Manager/FeedFile.php on line 173"

Comment: no, unfortunately, I haven't managed to solve the issue myself. I'm using something else to validate the XML or pray not to bump into it again.

Answer (score 0):

As XMLReader states, open method return boolean, which is TRUE in case of success and FALSE in case of failure. You may want to try the snippet below?

```
if (file_exists($name)) {
    $reader = new XMLReader();
    if ($reader->open($name)) {
        $reader->setSchema('inc/schema.xsd');
        while($reader->read());
        $reader->close();
    }
} else {
    die("you're having trouble with the files!");
}
```

Comment: same error / warning, but I see the logic. although, the snippet I've used includes an else die, the system doesn't go on this path.